# Vsts agent is not registering on a win 2012 R2 server

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, agent, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, agents

I am trying to install a VSTS agent on a win 2012 R2 server but it is failing with "An error occurred while sending the request. failed to connect "

I am not sure of what is going on here. I am behind a corporate firewall. But when  i tried it on my local system on the same domain and under the same firewall it is working.Only in that specific server it is not.

Can anyone help me out with the same? (could not post the whole hence copied from where it says connect)

Below is the response from the _diag folder

```
[2017-08-28 19:17:14Z INFO Terminal] WRITE LINE: 
[2017-08-28 19:17:14Z INFO Terminal] WRITE LINE: >> Connect:
[2017-08-28 19:17:14Z INFO Terminal] WRITE LINE: 
[2017-08-28 19:17:14Z INFO CommandSettings] Arg 'url': ''
[2017-08-28 19:17:14Z INFO CommandSettings] Flag 'unattended': 'False'
[2017-08-28 19:17:14Z INFO PromptManager] ReadValue
[2017-08-28 19:17:14Z INFO Terminal] WRITE: Enter server URL > 
[2017-08-28 19:17:14Z INFO Terminal] READ LINE
[2017-08-28 19:17:54Z INFO Terminal] Read value: 'https://xyz.visualstudio.com/'
[2017-08-28 19:17:54Z INFO ConfigurationManager] GetCredentialProvider
[2017-08-28 19:17:54Z INFO CommandSettings] Arg 'auth': ''
[2017-08-28 19:17:54Z INFO CommandSettings] Flag 'unattended': 'False'
[2017-08-28 19:17:54Z INFO PromptManager] ReadValue
[2017-08-28 19:17:54Z INFO Terminal] WRITE: Enter authentication type (press enter for PAT) > 
[2017-08-28 19:17:54Z INFO Terminal] READ LINE
[2017-08-28 19:17:55Z INFO Terminal] Read value: ''
[2017-08-28 19:17:55Z INFO PromptManager] Falling back to the default: 'PAT'
[2017-08-28 19:17:55Z INFO ConfigurationManager] Creating credential for auth: PAT
[2017-08-28 19:17:55Z INFO CredentialManager] GetCredentialProvider
[2017-08-28 19:17:55Z INFO CredentialManager] Creating type PAT
[2017-08-28 19:17:55Z INFO CredentialManager] Creating credential type: PAT
[2017-08-28 19:17:55Z INFO PersonalAccessToken] EnsureCredential
[2017-08-28 19:17:55Z INFO CommandSettings] Arg 'token': ''
[2017-08-28 19:17:55Z INFO CommandSettings] Flag 'unattended': 'False'
[2017-08-28 19:17:55Z INFO PromptManager] ReadValue
[2017-08-28 19:17:55Z INFO Terminal] WRITE: Enter personal access token > 
[2017-08-28 19:17:55Z INFO Terminal] READ SECRET
[2017-08-28 19:18:12Z INFO Terminal] Read value: '********'
[2017-08-28 19:18:12Z INFO PersonalAccessToken] GetVssCredentials
[2017-08-28 19:18:12Z INFO PersonalAccessToken] token retrieved: 52 chars
[2017-08-28 19:18:12Z INFO ConfigurationManager] cred retrieved
[2017-08-28 19:18:12Z INFO Terminal] WRITE LINE: Connecting to server ...
[2017-08-28 19:18:12Z INFO VisualStudioServices] Starting operation Location.GetConnectionData
[2017-08-28 19:18:34Z ERR  VisualStudioServices] GET request to https://xyz.visualstudio.com/_apis/connectionData?connectOptions=1&lastChangeId=-1&lastChangeId64=-1 failed. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The operation timed out
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
[2017-08-28 19:18:34Z INFO VisualStudioServices] Finished operation Location.GetConnectionData
[2017-08-28 19:18:34Z INFO AgentServer] Catch exception during connect. 4 attemp left.
[2017-08-28 19:18:34Z ERR  AgentServer] System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The operation timed out
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__46`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.<GetConnectionDataAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.<ConnectAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.AgentServer.<ConnectAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
[2017-08-28 19:18:34Z INFO VisualStudioServices] Starting operation Location.GetConnectionData
[2017-08-28 19:19:16Z ERR  VisualStudioServices] GET request to https://xyz.visualstudio.com/_apis/connectionData?connectOptions=1&lastChangeId=-1&lastChangeId64=-1 failed. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The operation timed out
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
[2017-08-28 19:19:16Z INFO VisualStudioServices] Finished operation Location.GetConnectionData
[2017-08-28 19:19:16Z INFO AgentServer] Catch exception during connect. 3 attemp left.
[2017-08-28 19:19:16Z ERR  AgentServer] System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The operation timed out
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__46`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.<GetConnectionDataAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.<ConnectAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.AgentServer.<ConnectAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
[2017-08-28 19:19:16Z INFO VisualStudioServices] Starting operation Location.GetConnectionData
[2017-08-28 19:19:59Z ERR  VisualStudioServices] GET request to https://xyz.visualstudio.com/_apis/connectionData?connectOptions=1&lastChangeId=-1&lastChangeId64=-1 failed. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The operation timed out
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
[2017-08-28 19:19:59Z INFO VisualStudioServices] Finished operation Location.GetConnectionData
[2017-08-28 19:19:59Z INFO AgentServer] Catch exception during connect. 2 attemp left.
[2017-08-28 19:19:59Z ERR  AgentServer] System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The operation timed out
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__46`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.<GetConnectionDataAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.<ConnectAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.AgentServer.<ConnectAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
[2017-08-28 19:19:59Z INFO VisualStudioServices] Starting operation Location.GetConnectionData
[2017-08-28 19:20:41Z ERR  VisualStudioServices] GET request to https://xyz.visualstudio.com/_apis/connectionData?connectOptions=1&lastChangeId=-1&lastChangeId64=-1 failed. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The operation timed out
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
[2017-08-28 19:20:41Z INFO VisualStudioServices] Finished operation Location.GetConnectionData
[2017-08-28 19:20:41Z INFO AgentServer] Catch exception during connect. 1 attemp left.
[2017-08-28 19:20:41Z ERR  AgentServer] System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The operation timed out
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__46`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.<GetConnectionDataAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.<ConnectAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.AgentServer.<ConnectAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
[2017-08-28 19:20:41Z INFO VisualStudioServices] Starting operation Location.GetConnectionData
[2017-08-28 19:21:23Z ERR  VisualStudioServices] GET request to https://xyz.visualstudio.com/_apis/connectionData?connectOptions=1&lastChangeId=-1&lastChangeId64=-1 failed. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The operation timed out
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
[2017-08-28 19:21:23Z INFO VisualStudioServices] Finished operation Location.GetConnectionData
[2017-08-28 19:21:23Z INFO CommandSettings] Flag 'unattended': 'False'
[2017-08-28 19:21:23Z ERR  Terminal] WRITE ERROR (exception):
[2017-08-28 19:21:23Z ERR  Terminal] System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The operation timed out
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__46`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.<GetConnectionDataAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.<ConnectAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.AgentServer.<ConnectAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Configuration.BuildReleasesAgentConfigProvider.<TestConnectionAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.<ConfigureAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
[2017-08-28 19:21:23Z ERR  Terminal] WRITE ERROR: Failed to connect.  Try again or ctrl-c to quit
[2017-08-28 19:21:23Z INFO CommandSettings] Arg 'url': ''
[2017-08-28 19:21:23Z INFO CommandSettings] Flag 'unattended': 'False'
[2017-08-28 19:21:23Z INFO PromptManager] ReadValue
[2017-08-28 19:21:23Z INFO Terminal] WRITE: Enter server URL > 
[2017-08-28 19:21:23Z INFO Terminal] READ LINE
```

Comment: Did you retry to configure the same agent more that 5 times or did you take more than a few minutes to configure? You can refer https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#workaround-httptimeoutexception for timeout issue. And what's the result if you extract the file in another path and try again?

Comment: Thanks Marina for trying to help out.....I might have tried with the same agent more than 5 times. I will try downloading another copy if it helps and check the results. On the second part "did you take more than a few mins to configue?" I am not sure that I understand the question correctly. And yes..I tried changing the path but then also it id not work.

Comment: In the link I offered  to you, there has two variables: `VSTS_HTTP_RETRY` (default value is 5 times) and `VSTS_HTTP_TIMEOUT` (default time out is 100 seconds). And the two variables can be changed by setting bigger values in environment variables. But if you tried to config the agent more than 10 times, you'd better copy it in another path and try again.

Comment: Thanks Marina for pointing towards the link...I just now got my solution from there. For this particular server I had to mention the proxy and it is now working as expected. While for the other servers this proxy was not required. hence was not able to understand what was going on. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction forward.

Comment: Glad to hear the problem has been solved, you can mark your answer 24 hours later. And it will benefit for others who have similar questions :)

Comment: Marina...actually I have a lot of doubts regarding too many other things as well regarding the agents. I am very new with MS technologies and hence am not able to understand the concept of CI-CD with VSTS. Is there a good tutorial that you could suggest me to refer or any other help regarding the same..?

Comment: Yes, there is an example  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/get-started/ci-cd-part-1 to explain how CI build and CD deploy for VSTS. And you can also refer the whole parts https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/overview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the proxy not set. As soon as I set the VSTS_HTTP_PROXY with the value of our corporate proxy, the agent got registered like a charm and is working as expected.
Thanks to Marina for pointing me in the right direction